# How can I convert random items from a list to string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a simple hangman code, and I'm having some difficulty with creating a counter to mark correct/incorrect guesses based on the number of letters in a list. I try to convert the output to a string using an expression, but it still returns as type(None).

Here's what I've tried:

```
wordz = ('cat dog chipmunk whale tiger giraffe')
a = wordz.split( )
import random
r = print(random.choice(a))
print(a)
r = print(str(random.choice(a)))
```

I've also tried this below for the conversion, it works, in a sense, but I need to make it static so it gives me the length of the original word output (e.g. chipmunk, 8). It gave me (chipmunk, 4) which I'm guessing is because it goes back to the word list and chooses a different word to count:

```
f = print(len(str(random.choice(a))))
turns = len(f)
print(len(f))
```

Comment: Don't assign to a `print()`. `r = print(random.choice(a))` should be `print(random.choice(a))`

Comment: assign **what** you want to to print to r, not the print function itself. That way you can re-use it later on for the length

Comment: @Eric, `wordz` isn't a tuple. It is missing a trailing comma to make it a tuple.  The parentheses are unnecessary but not problematic.

Comment: Thank you, guys! It worked!

Comment: You are completely correct @user1558604 I overlooked it as the code wasn't formatted yet when I commented it.

Comment: Also worth noting, your random choices are already strings. There's no reason to call, for example, `str('cat')`, because that's just `'cat'` again

Comment: I'm voting to close this. It's all over the place, and I can't see it being that relevant in the future.

Comment: Why not use a list?